# Rage downvoting?

Tags: discussion

Sieht so aus als würde ein user mich wahllos "downvoten", evtl. weil ich ihm vorher bedeutete sein Post würde eine Frage nicht beantworten. Mit gezielten Votes habe ich auch ja keine Probleme, aber akzeptierte Antworten nur so aus Wut & Rache muß ja auch nicht sein, oder?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Es kommt leider immer wieder vor, das Leute nicht allein und objektiv die Qualität eines Beitrags mit ihren Votes beurteilen, sondern eine Art Sympathie oder Antipathie gegenüber anderen entwickeln, was zu einem auffälligen und von uns ungewollten Stimmverhalten führen kann.

Weil wir das so nicht wollen und weil durch solch eine Verhalten die Qualität eines Beitrags nicht mehr so genau durch die Votes bestimmt werden kann, hat das "System" (das sind Algorithmen der Software) einen Mechanismus eingebaut, der genau solch ein Voting-Verhalten entdecken kann und dann auch rückgängig macht.

Wir Moderatoren können dazu nichts machen, auch wir sehen nicht, wer welche Votes abgibt. Es soll wirklich eine geheime Abstimmung sein, die wir alle so machen dürfen, wie wir es wollen und für richtig halten.

Mehr zu den Serienvotes hier:

- [Help Center > Serial Votes](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/serial-voting-reversed)